# Content alignment in ITEXT footer/header

Tags: itext

hie ..

i have been using itext for the past couple of days and i am facing difficulty in aligning footer content .. if there are two or more lines in footer, is there a way to align each line differently .. i ve tried doing it in the following manner without any success ..

```
Paragraph footerInfo = new Paragraph("Date :-",FontFactory.getFont("Calibri",9,Font.BOLD));   
 footerInfo.add("\n");
 footerInfo.add(new Paragraph("Place :- "",FontFactory.getFont("Calibri",9,Font.BOLD)));

Paragraph foot1 = new Paragraph("EmpID:-",FontFactory.getFont("Calibri",9,Font.BOLD));
          foot1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
          footerInfo.add(foot1);


  HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(footerInfo, false);
    footer.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
    document.setFooter(footer);
```

Comment: HeaderFooter has not been the mechanism of choice for creating headers and footers with iText for many years. Have a look at page events. In the onEndPage page event you can position any number of text fragments anywhere on the page.

Comment: What mkl says is correct. You are using a class that was removed from iText in 2009, so you are using a mighty old (and totally unsupported) version of iText. Please upgrade to a more recent version. If you need more reasons to stop using an obsolete version of iText, read http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq

Comment: thanks for the comments .. i shall look into the recent versions and try to resolve the issue ..